# При сохранении триггера "before*update" появляется ошибка 1064 - MySQL

Tags: mysql, триггер

**Используется**
MySQL - 5.7 - х64
HeidiSQL -9.4

При сохранении триггера "before*update" появляется ошибка 1064.
"You have an error in your SQl syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to user near"

Привожу триггер.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_02_1_test_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `trg_02_1_test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO trg
     Set
     id_tbl_02_n_log = NEW.id_tbl_02_1;

END;
```

**Вопрос.**
Как можно решить проблему ?

**Основная таблица**

```
CREATE TABLE `trg_02_1_test` (
    `id_tbl_02_1` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cur_datetime_tbl_02_1` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pol_1_date_tbl_02_1` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pol_2_enum_tbl_02_1` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1` TEXT NULL,
    `pol_5_int_tbl_02_1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_tbl_02_1`)
)
LONGTEXT\r\n'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=7
;
```

**Таблица журнала**

```
CREATE TABLE `trg` (
    `datetime_log` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `tbl_02_name_log` TEXT NULL,
    `id_tbl_02_n_log` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tbl_02_pol_name_log` TEXT NULL,
    `tbl_02_pol_content_log` TEXT NULL
)
LONGTEXT\r\n'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Mike Что-то не понял, как это можно применить.. Я использую HeidiSQL.. А она автоматически проставлетс начаьлный код и недаёт рдактировать.. http://prntscr.com/e9j70d

Comment: попробуйте для начала записать в файл с указаниями delimiter и выполнить с помощью mysql, т.е. не из этой среды. и посмотреть будет ошибка или нет. И потом копать дальше. проверить insert с этими именами таблицы/поля с фиксированным значением вместо new

Comment: @Mike  Буду разбираться... Вы не знаете почему в рабочем и нерабочем варианте триггеров цвет названия таблиц отличается ? См. скрин по ссылке http://prntscr.com/e9jz4b

Comment: может trg зарезервированное слово в MySQL и если таблица так называется ее надо заключать в обратные апострофы

Comment: @Mike Переименовал - цвет не поменялся.. Заключил в апострофы, цвет изменился.. http://prntscr.com/e9ka6z

Comment: @Mike Проблема решена.. Разместил в командной строке(или как это место называется), нажал F9(запуск). Триггер создался..http://prntscr.com/e9l94k  Изменил вопрос: уточнил, что решить нужно в программе HeidiSQl.. В общем не знаю.. Наверное оформляйте как ответ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась за счёт конструкции типа

```
INSERT INTO tab1(fld1) VALUES(val1)
```

Т.е. триггер в моём случае будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_02_1_test_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `trg_02_1_test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
/*РАБОТАЕТ ДАТА*/
  IF (NOT OLD.pol_1_date_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_1_date_tbl_02_1)
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO trg_02_00_log(tbl_02_tbl_name_log, id_tbl_02_n_log, tbl_02_pol_name_log, tbl_02_pol_content_log)  
    VALUES('trg_02_1_test', NEW.id_tbl_02_1, 'pol_1_date_tbl_02_1' ,NEW.pol_1_date_tbl_02_1); 
  END IF;

    /*РАБОТАЕТ enum*/
  IF (NOT OLD.pol_2_enum_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_2_enum_tbl_02_1)
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO trg_02_00_log(tbl_02_tbl_name_log, id_tbl_02_n_log, tbl_02_pol_name_log, tbl_02_pol_content_log)  
    VALUES('trg_02_1_test', NEW.id_tbl_02_1, 'tbl_02_pol_name_log' ,NEW.pol_2_enum_tbl_02_1); 
  END IF;

    /*РАБОТАЕТ longtxt*/
  IF (NOT OLD.pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1)
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO trg_02_00_log(tbl_02_tbl_name_log, id_tbl_02_n_log, tbl_02_pol_name_log, tbl_02_pol_content_log)  
    VALUES('trg_02_1_test', NEW.id_tbl_02_1, 'pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1' ,NEW.pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1); 
  END IF;

    /*РАБОТАЕТ ТЕКСТ*/
    IF (NOT OLD.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1)
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO trg_02_00_log(tbl_02_tbl_name_log, id_tbl_02_n_log, tbl_02_pol_name_log, tbl_02_pol_content_log)  
    VALUES('trg_02_1_test', NEW.id_tbl_02_1, 'pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1' ,NEW.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1); 
  END IF;

    /*РАБОТАЕТ int*/
  IF (NOT OLD.pol_5_int_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_5_int_tbl_02_1)
    THEN  
    INSERT INTO trg_02_00_log(tbl_02_tbl_name_log, id_tbl_02_n_log, tbl_02_pol_name_log, tbl_02_pol_content_log)  
    VALUES('trg_02_1_test', NEW.id_tbl_02_1, 'pol_5_int_tbl_02_1' ,NEW.pol_5_int_tbl_02_1); 
  END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_02_1_test_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `trg_02_1_test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO trg
     Set
     @id_tbl_02_n_log = NEW.id_tbl_02_1;

END;
```

Comment: при insert в таблицу (см. предыдущую строку, set - ее продолжение) присвоить значение переменной ... ну ну ...

Comment: Ну это уже будет другая ошибка ахах

Comment: @Zakhar Telyatnikov Та же ошибка